# Revert changes from tooltip

Tags: d3.js

I have a working scatterplot of the classic iris dataset in d3 (code not shown). I added a dropdown button to so that it has the 3 species to chose from. When a user changes the drop down, the color of the selected group is changed to whatever color (pink in this case). The tooltip I have highlights an individual point and changes the radius and color. When you 'mouseout' it changes the color back to the original color (instead of if the group is selected, the color should be pink).

```
  var dots = bounds.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("cx", d => xScale(xAccessor(d)))
      .attr("cy", d => yScale(yAccessor(d)))
      .attr("r", function(d){if (sizeAccessor(d) < 3){return 2}else{return 2.5}})
      .attr("fill",d => color(colorAccessor(d)))
      .on("mouseenter",DoThis)
      .on("mouseleave",RevertThis)
  function updateColor(sss){   
    dots  
      .attr("fill",function(d){
          if(d.species == sss)
              {return "pink"}
          else{return color(colorAccessor(d))}
        })
    }
  var dropdown = d3.select('#dd')
  dropdown.selectAll('option')
    .data(specs)
    .enter().append("option")
    .attr("value",d=>d)
    .text(d => d)
  dropdown.on('change',function(d){
    var selvalue = this.value     
    //d3.selectAll('circle').remove()  
    //console.table(filt)  
    updateColor(selvalue)
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

This accomplished changing the color of the dots by 'species':

```
  function updateColor(sss){   
    dots  
      .attr("fill",function(d){
          if(d.species == sss)
              {return "pink"}
          else{return color(colorAccessor(d))}
      })
  }
  var dropdown = d3.select('#dd')
  dropdown.selectAll('option')
    .data(specs)
    .enter().append("option")
    .attr("value",d=>d)
    .text(d => d)
  dropdown.on('change',function(d){
    var selvalue = this.value     
    //d3.selectAll('circle').remove()  
    updateColor(selvalue)
  })
```